# Trouble printing a list within a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to print a list within a list, but not this way:

```
print(myList[1])
```

I want to be able to search through the list, find the correct list based on a user input and print the appropriate list. This is my code so far:

```
myList = [['E1234','12/09/14','440','A','0'],['E3431','10/01/12','320','N','120'],['E0987','04/12/16','342','A','137']]
prompt = input("Enter a player name: ")

if prompt in myList:
    print(myList["""What do I put in here???"""])
```

So if I entered "E1234" as `prompt`, I want this code to look through `myList`, pick up the list and display it. Please help me, I'm stuck.

**Update**

Sorry that I haven't mentioned it before, but the boundaries are to use lists, not dictionaries.

Comment: Is there a reason for the outer structure to be a list rather than a dictionary?

Comment: The boundaries are to use lists, not dictionaries. But thanks for that

Comment: Is it possible for `prompt` to appear in more than one list?

Comment: No, it `prompt` must be a unique number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit @kingledion answered, the correct implementation would probably be to use a dictionary. If you insist on this list of lists data structure, you could use a list comprehension to filter out only the relevant lists:

```
details = [x for x in myList if x[0] == prompt]
if details:
    print details
```

Comment: Nice that this handles `prompt` appearing more than once; however, output is different from what OP requested (should be `details[0]`).

Answer (score 4):

The implementation you are thinking of is a dict().

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

A dict provides you with the ability to access data by a key, in this case the player name.

```
mydict = {'E1234': ['12/09/14','440','A','0'],'E3431': ['10/01/12','320','N','120'],'E0987': ['04/12/16','342','A','137']}
prompt = input("Enter a player name: ")

print(mydict.get(prompt, "Player not found"))
```

EDIT:

Also you can turn a list into a dict using:

```
mydict = {key: value for (key, value) in [(x[0], [x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]]) for x in myList]}
```

EDIT2:

Ok fine, if you are not allowed to use dictionaries at all, then simulate one:

```
fake_dict_keys = [x[0] for x in myList]
print(myList[fake_dict_keys.index(prompt)])
```

Comment: That's nice if OP has control over the representation of the data to be searched; it isn't clear form the question that this is the case.

Comment: The boundaries are that I have to use lists

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your list to a dictionary and then do the task. Example below:

```
myList = [['E1234','12/09/14','440','A','0'],['E3431','10/01/12','320','N','120'],['E0987','04/12/16','342','A','137']]

myDict = { i[0]: i for i in myList }

prompt = input("Enter a player name: ")

if prompt in myDict:
    print(myDict[prompt])
```

Comment: This assumes that no more than 1 element shares the same first value.

Comment: Yes, but, as far as the problem described by the OP, that is the case. The instruction "prompt in myList" means that there is only one occurence, that name is something like an ID.

Comment: "prompt in myList" says nothing more that it appears at least once; thinking it is an ID is an assumption made by you.

Comment: Your assumption that it is not is also yours, bear that in mind. Until the OP says otherwise, we can each assume anything that we want.

Comment: I made no such assumption, and I challenge you to point to *any* evidence that I did.

Comment: Wow, so much ego :) I challenge you to say why you voted down my answer first. Why is this answer any less legitimate than other answers on this post? The previous answer is also based on dictionaries.

Comment: You make an untrue claim, and when called on it, ask why I did something you have no evidence that I did.  I think we're done here.