# Printing a list within a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am attempting to print a list within a list. I know, I have posted a similar question before - [Trouble printing a list within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922150/trouble-printing-a-list-within-a-list), but this is a different issue within the same topic, so please don't flag this as duplicate. I have merged two codes together and this is the final code. In the if statement, I am attempting to print the details of a certain customer of which the user has entered as `customer_number`. The code searches through `myList`, which `Payments.txt` has been appended to. The code can do all of this, but the problem is that it prints this out multiple times; 6 times to be precise:

```
[['E1234', '12/09/14', '440', 'A', '0']]
Customer number:  E1234
Date of payment:  12/09/14
Payment Amount:  440
Paid Amount:  0
```

This is my code:

```
print("Option A: Show a record\nOption Q: Quit")
decision = input("Enter A or Q: ")
myList = []

if decision == "A" or decision == "a":
    myFile = open("Payments.txt")
    customer_number = input("Enter a customer number to view their scores: ")
    record = myFile.readlines()
    for line in record:
        myList.append(line.strip().split(','))
        details = [x for x in myList if x[0] == customer_number]
        if details:
            print(details)
            print("Customer number: ", details[0][0])
            print("Date of payment: ", details[0][1])
            print("Payment Amount: ", details[0][2])
            print("Paid Amount: ", details[0][4])
    myFile.close()
    print(myList)

elif decision == "Q" or "q":
    exit
```

Comment: `elif decision == "Q" or "q":` should probably be `elif decision == "Q" or decision == "q":`

Comment: `decision in set('Qq')`

Comment: Or perhaps `elif decision.lower() == 'q':`

Comment: @PeterWood why do you need a set? *decision in 'Qq'* ?

Comment: @palsch You don't *need* it for two values, and creating the `set` just once is expensive. However if you have more than 2 values and you're comparing more than just once, it's more efficient than a linear search, especially if the set has been created beforehand.

Comment: @palsch `timeit("'stop' in quit", "quit = set(['q', 'quit', 'exit', 'stop'])")` gives `0.056` on my machine

Comment: @palsch `timeit("'stop' in quit", "quit = ['q', 'quit', 'exit', 'stop']")` gives `0.101`

Comment: @PeterWood ah, OK, clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exit the loop when you find and print an answer.

```
if details:
    print(details)
    print("Customer number: ", details[0][0])
    print("Date of payment: ", details[0][1])
    print("Payment Amount: ", details[0][2])
    print("Paid Amount: ", details[0][4])
    break
```

Comment: Thanks, should have realised that!